# Combining multiple API calls into one .json file

Tags: python

I am attempting to make multiple api calls for different input values. I successfully created a for loop that will input the parameters into the url, but I am having trouble combining the api call results into one .json file. The end goal will be to export the data as a .csv that can be analyzed. Here is the code I have been trying:

```
`urls = ['www.ibm.com', 'www.salesforce.com', 'www.google.com']
 items = []
 for url in urls:
      x = ('http://partnerapi.com/partnerapi/company/detail?CompanyDomain=%s&pc=TestKey.partner&key=0&outputtype=json&outputFieldOptions=companyTopLevelIndustry') % (url)
      call = requests.get(x).json()
      items.extend(call['items'])`
```

I am getting a keyerror: 'items'

Comment: Going to [partnerapi](http://partnerapi.com/partnerapi/company/detail?CompanyDomain=www.google.com&pc=TestKey.partner&key=0&outputtype=json&outputFieldOptions=companyTopLevelIndustry) reveals that the server returns HTML, not JSON

Comment: `KeyError` means you are trying to get a key from `dict` *call* which is missing. You can check the response of the API call and then parse accordingly with proper error handling.